# how can I write a formula that uses a cell's contents when building a range reference to the name of another sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a large Google Sheets spreadsheet that has individual sheets for financial statements of activity for multiple years. I want to reference particular columns of those in other sheets, and I've successfully figured out how to do that with an HLOOKUP function. However, because I want to do this for multiple years, I'd like that HLOOKUP function to pick up the name of the sheet to reference from its column header. Right now, I'm hard-coding it like this—you can see the HLOOKUP range refers to cells in the "2021 Overall" sheet. The hard-coded approach works but makes adding a new year tedious. Ideally, the HLOOKUP formula would read the contents of its column header cell to determine which year it is.

[image]

As best I can tell, the solution is to use INDIRECT, but I can't figure out any way to build the formulate with INDIRECT and not get an error. For instance, this seemed like it should work. As you can see, I have 2021 in cell D4, and my INDIRECT statement is referencing that and building the rest of the range.

[image]

I've also tried using INDIRECT with an explicit CONCATENATE, with no more success.

[image]

Any ideas for how to look up that D4 cell and slide it into the HLOOKUP range?

Thank you!

Comment: Kindly provide a sample spreadsheet with the expected result. See [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Certainly— here's a link to a world-editable sample spreadsheet. The various formulas I've tried are in Row 13; Row 5 identifies which test is which in each of the year columns. The 2018, 2017, and 2016 year columns are available for testing.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jfv8jM-uEggCfoEJmECq2D19xQNdN7W0WVI5avpXh64/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Forgot to mention. When the formulas work, the cells should either be empty or bring in data in various spots (E17, G24, H13, H17, I17, and K17).

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the `"'"&` before D4 and the `'` after the Overall.

Your formula should look like this:

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP($A$2,INDIRECT(F4 &" Overall!$A$5:$X$150", Utility!$A10, FALSE)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion—I hadn't thought about removing the single quotes from the sheet reference. Unfortunately, it made no difference; the error continues.

Comment: @AdamC.Engst - Remove the extra `'(` before INDIRECT, the `'` after `Overall!$A$5:$X$150")` and the `)` after `FALSE`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this! Your suggestion put me on the right track, and I finally got a variant that works, which is this:

`=IFERROR(HLOOKUP($A$2,INDIRECT("'"&F$4&" Overall'!$A$5:$X$150"), Utility!$A3, FALSE))`

What's truly odd is that Google Sheets wouldn't accept the formula as pasted; I had to type it. I encountered that in my test sheet and again when I tried to replicate it in my live spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, I was pasting directly into the formula text box, rather than over the cell in general—no difference. But once I'd gotten Google Sheets to acknowledge the formula once, it was fine from then on. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With Nikko's nudges in the right direction, I eventually figured out the right format. This allows the formula to work in multiple sheets and to be filled right (for more years) and down (for more classes).

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP($A$2,INDIRECT("'"D$4&" Overall'!$A$5:$X$150"), Utility!$A3, FALSE))
```

Note that if you try to replicate this, you may need to type the formula out from scratch—I had a problem where pasting it in didn't work. Once I'd retyped it and Google Sheets acknowledged it, it worked from then on in the spreadsheet, even when pasted from sheet to sheet.